# Игнорирует проверку строки и сразу выводит "NO" после нажатия кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Клавиатурный тренажер")
root.geometry("400x300")

def rule_game():
    tea = StringVar()
    message_entry = StringVar()
    message_entry = Entry()
    tea=message_entry.get()
    slova = StringVar()
    slova = "abcd"
    if message_entry.get() == slova:
        label1 = Label(text="Result", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()
    else:
        label1 = Label(text="NO", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

def start_game():
    message = StringVar()
    play_game()
    global wow_button
    wow_button = Button(text="Click Me", command=rule_game)
    wow_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
def play_game():
    destroy_object = [btn_1]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()
    message = StringVar()
    message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message)
    message_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c")
    poetry = "abcd"
    global label2
    label2 = Label(text=poetry, justify=LEFT)
    label2.place(relx=.3, rely=.3)


btn_1 = Button(text="start",  # текст кнопки
               background="#555",  # фоновый цвет кнопки
               foreground="#ccc",  # цвет текста
               padx="20",  # отступ от границ до содержимого по горизонтали
               pady="8",  # отступ от границ до содержимого по вертикали
               font="16",  # высота шрифта
               command=start_game
               )
btn_1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Во-первых, вопрос должен быть на русском языке, во-вторых, стоит добавить более подробное объяснение, чем текущее поведение отличается от желаемого

Comment: На русском стеке вопрос тоже на русском. Название переменных и функций лучше поменять, это несерьезно же :) А код `wow_button = Button(text="Click Me", command=pravila_debilov())` будет вести себя не так, как вы ожидаете, т.к. в `command` попадет не ссылка на функцию, а `None`, причем сразу же после выполнения `pravila_debilov()`. А нужно так: `wow_button = Button(text="Click Me", command=pravila_debilov)`

Comment: Поставил минус за такие названия, это просто неуважение. Исправит - уберу минус.

Comment: извините,забыл убрать)

Comment: @CrazyElf теперь оно не выводит перманентно "NO",но все же игнорирует цикл на проверку строки и сразу выводит "NO" после нажатия кнопки

Comment: Совершенно не игнорирует. Просто ты почему-то думаешь, что message_entry.get() равно "abcd", а на самом деле нет. И если тебе кажется, что программа ведет себя неправильно, то это не так - программа ведет себя так, как написана. 100%. Это просто ты ожидаешь от нее неправильного. Или неправильно написал.

Answer (score 2):

В этом фрагменте кода:

```
message_entry = Entry()
tea=message_entry.get()

slova = "abcd"
if message_entry.get() == slova:
    label1 = Label(text="Result", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
    label1.pack()
else:
    label1 = Label(text="NO", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
    label1.pack()
```

- вы создаете новое текстовое поле, сразу пытаетесь из него что-то прочитать, но на момент создания в текстовом поле еще пусто - пользователь физически не успеет за микросекунды между выполнением этих команд что-то ввести (к тому же, данное текстовое поле вы не размещаете в окне с помощью pack/grid/place). Дальше условие в if не выполнится, потому что пустая строка, полученная из текстового поля, не равна строке `"abcd"`, в итоге получаете NO.

По логике, вам нужно получать данные из текстового поля `message_entry`, созданного в функции `play_game`, а не создавать новое текстовое поле. Переменная `message_entry`, созданная в `rule_game`, никак не связана с переменной `message_entry` в `play_game`. Чтобы получать данные из `message_entry`, созданного в `play_game`, нужно в этой функции объявить эту  переменную глобальной (или переменную `message` объявить глобальной, и получать данные из нее):

```
def rule_game():
    slova = "abcd"
    if message_entry.get() == slova:
        label1 = Label(text="Result", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()
    else:
        label1 = Label(text="NO", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

...

def play_game():
    global message_entry
    ...
    message = StringVar()
    message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message)
    message_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c")
```

или через `message`:

```
def rule_game():
    slova = "abcd"
    if message.get() == slova:
        label1 = Label(text="Result", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()
    else:
        label1 = Label(text="NO", fg="#eee", bg="#333")
        label1.pack()

...

def play_game():
    global message
    ...
    message = StringVar()
    message_entry = Entry(textvariable=message)
    message_entry.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c")
```